# Cpp file says [converted] and is a bunch of random characters

Tags: c++, vim, vi

[image: better picture]

My code was converted to these random characters at some point after I saved my program using Vi. I did this project for a grade in one of my college courses and didn’t get any credit, despite the fact that I spent hours working on my code for this to happen. If anyone knows how to convert it back to C++ I would be thankful.

[image: random characters]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203697/discussion-on-question-by-anne-cpp-file-says-converted-and-is-a-bunch-of-rando).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had saved my file under the wrong folder and I was able to recover my original file. Thanks to all for helping out with this! It seems like it always tends to be something so simple...

Comment: Good news! ::-) I'm glad it worked out.